# c# Export datagridview to excel without hidden columns

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

i`m trying to export the datagridview to excel file but i made some columns in datagridview is visible how i can export only visible columns to excel file

my code

```
for (int i = 1; i < datagrid.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
{
    if(datagrid.Columns[i - 1].Visible)
        worksheet.Cells[1, i] = datagrid.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}
for (int i = 0; i < datagrid.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < datagrid.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (datagrid.Columns[j].Visible)
            worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = datagrid.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString(); //
    }
}
```

i get this result

[image]

there more columns in sheet is empty i wanna make it like this

[image]

Comment: Was the DataGridView setup with a `DataSource`?

Comment: i solved the problem bro thanks so much i removed the visible from datagridview